# Is it possible to run a git hook that is executed when adding a file?

Tags: git, hooks

I'm planning to set up a client side git hook to force a commit to fail if any file in the commit contains the text "donotcommit".

Is it possible to hook the execution of "git add", such that I can run a shell script at the time files are added, and permit or deny the add based on the exit status of the shell script.

Comment: see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is not. However, there is a workaround.

Git lets you filter files before staging (and before checkout), if needed. You can hook right there. See the [filter section in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code)

For example, lets say, all .txt files may not contain the word `donotcommit`. First, we create the filter in `.git/config` or in your global config file:

```
[filter "donotcommit"]
    clean = bash -c 'tee >(cat) | grep donotcommit -qi && exit 1 || exit 0'
    smudge = cat
    required
```

The clean filter is run on `add`, the smudge filter on checkout. `required` tells git that whenever this command fails, the file is in a bad state and can not be added. The command receives the file-contents piped to stdin, and since it's a *filter* and what it outputs gets added as file-content, we need to make sure to pass the whole file through, thats what the `tee >(cat)` in `clean` and the `cat` in smudge is for. The `| grep donotcommit -q && exit 1 || exit 0` part should be clear: Look for `donotcommit` (case insensitive), if found, exit with an error (1), otherwise exit cleanly (0).

Then, register this filter for txt-files in the repositories `.gitattributes` file

```
*.txt filter=donotcommit
```

Result:

```
C:\dev\test>echo Hello World > test.txt

C:\dev\test>git add test.txt

C:\dev\test>echo Hello World [DONOTCOMMIT] > test.txt

C:\dev\test>git add test.txt
error: external filter 'bash -c 'tee >(cat) | grep donotcommit -qi && exit 1 || exit 0'' failed 1
error: external filter 'bash -c 'tee >(cat) | grep donotcommit -qi && exit 1 || exit 0'' failed
fatal: test.txt: clean filter 'donotcommit' failed

C:\dev\test>
```

Comment: Regretfully, while this works, it's a little overzealous.  Not only is the filter run when doing a `git add` but also when doing a `git status`.  That causes problems if any currently unstaged file has the `donotcommit` trigger string in it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to run on `git status` for me, at least I don't see a error message